# Google Analytics automate filter management

Tags: filter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I use analytics.js and made some custom dimensions. One of my dimensions is "network". 
When someone is reffered from a partner network I send the ID of that network to Analytics.

example:
when someone is referred from Commission Junction I set

ga('set', 'dimension1', '4000');

In my reports however, i replaced '4000' by '4000 Commission Junction'

For this I've made a custom search and replace filter on the custom dimension column

Question: is it possible to manage these custom filters in an automated way? Ideally I would like to import all filters from a file (eg excel or txt file)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to manage filters using the API. There is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=192) for this that you can subscribe to.